# Java command to show the processus

Tags: java, command, jmx

hi i want to show the jboss 7 as process information and the database sessions information in java code...
i try this code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                    (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
```

and this code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
                    ("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\PSTools\\pslist.exe -s 2");
```

and it works good but it works only on windows operating system .
so i want to a java code which work on each operating system, and not only on windows or linux ...
can u help me please?
thanks for everybody.

Comment: .exe would not work in linux.

Comment: i know but i want to a way or a command that allows to me to knoe this information and work on all os

Comment: Did you try from the linux command prompt

Comment: no but the project manager tell me that we want to a java command and not to command of os

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is only suported for Windows operating system you need to find an alternate for this command in linux, or try adding the linux path in the parameters, it might work then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding java processes on the same host is fairly straight forward (some caveats listed later). Connecting to their JMX interfaces is also achievable. As far as tracking database sessions, you can conceptually acquire any data you want, as long as it is published through an accessible MBean.

The process requires using the [Java Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html). Here's a simple example where I will list all the JVM's running on my host, attempt to attach to them and list their heap usage.

First off, here's the imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;
import java.util.List;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor;
```

The **com.sun.tools.attach** classes are in your JVM's **tools.jar**. Here's the code:

```
public class AttachAPIExample {

    /**
     * Uses the attach API to locate all JVMs accessible on this machine.
     * @param args None
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get my PID
        final String MYPID = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0];
        log("Scanning for JVMs...");
        // List all the Virtual Machine Descriptors
        List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> descriptors = VirtualMachine.list(); 
        for(VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd: descriptors) {
            VirtualMachine vm = null;
            // Do this in a catch block in case we run into a JVM that is not the same "bit" as we are
            try {
                vm = vmd.provider().attachVirtualMachine(vmd.id());
                String display = vmd.displayName().trim().isEmpty() ? "Unknown" : vmd.displayName();
                log("JVM%sPID: %s Display: %s", vmd.id().equals(MYPID) ? " (Me) " : " ", vmd.id(), display);
                String connectorAddress = vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress", null);
                if(connectorAddress!=null) {
                    log("\tConnector Found Installed at [%s]", connectorAddress);
                } else {
                    String javaHome = vm.getSystemProperties().getProperty("java.home");
                    File agentJarFile = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "management-agent.jar");
                    if(agentJarFile.exists()) {
                        log("I think we can find this JVM's management agent here: [%s]", agentJarFile.toString());
                        vm.loadAgent(agentJarFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        connectorAddress = vm.getAgentProperties().getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress", null);
                        log("\tConnector Installed at [%s]", connectorAddress);
                    } else {
                        log("Cannot find the agent jar for JVM [%s] at [%s]", vmd.id(), javaHome);
                    }
                }
                // Now lets try and connect and read some MBean values
                if(connectorAddress!=null) {
                    log("Attaching to JVM [%s]...", vmd.id());
                    JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress);
                    JMXConnector connector = null;
                    try {
                        connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxUrl);
                        MBeanServerConnection conn = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
                        MemoryUsage heap = MemoryUsage.from((CompositeData)conn.getAttribute(new ObjectName(ManagementFactory.MEMORY_MXBEAN_NAME), "HeapMemoryUsage"));
                        log("Heap Usage: %s", heap);
                    } finally {
                        if(connector!=null) {
                            try { connector.close(); } catch (Exception ex) {/* No Op */}
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                /* No Op */
            } finally {
                if(vm!=null) try { vm.detach(); } catch (Exception ex) {/* No Op */}
                             log("======================================");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void log(String fmt, Object...args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(fmt, args));
    }

}
```

And here's some sample output:

```
Scanning for JVMs...
JVM PID: 27928 Display: sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
    Connector Found Installed at [service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/stub/rO0ABXNyAC5qYXZheC5tYW5hZ2VtZW50LnJlbW90ZS5ybWkuUk1JU2VydmVySW1wbF9TdHViAAAAAAAAAAICAAB4cgAaamF2YS5ybWkuc2VydmVyLlJlbW90ZVN0dWLp/tzJi+FlGgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc3AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADDEwLjEyLjExNC4zNwAA9bhcC21U1Z9PMPLlR/0AAAFAxsF5moACAHg=]
Attaching to JVM [27928]...
Heap Usage: init = 8388608(8192K) used = 40242696(39299K) committed = 44236800(43200K) max = 5726666752(5592448K)
======================================
JVM PID: 25028 Display: org.jboss.Main -c ecseu -b 0.0.0.0
I think we can find this JVM's management agent here: [c:\java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\lib\management-agent.jar]
    Connector Installed at [service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/stub/rO0ABXNyAC5qYXZheC5tYW5hZ2VtZW50LnJlbW90ZS5ybWkuUk1JU2VydmVySW1wbF9TdHViAAAAAAAAAAICAAB4cgAaamF2YS5ybWkuc2VydmVyLlJlbW90ZVN0dWLp/tzJi+FlGgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc4AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADVBQLVdLLU5XSEktMDEAAPjJTzYbxtjrUKazaPTEAAABQMuKX+6ABAB4]
Attaching to JVM [25028]...
Heap Usage: init = 1073741824(1048576K) used = 173876432(169801K) committed = 982581248(959552K) max = 982581248(959552K)
======================================
```

**Caveats**

1. JMVs can only attach to like bit JVMs (i.e. 32bit to 32bit, 64bit to 64bit)
2. The OS user launching the attach must have the OS authorization to access other processed. So same user, no problem. Other user... you should be root.
3. The attach api has mixed results when used across different JVM vendor implementations. ie. if it's Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK, you're probably good. If it's those, and you're trying to connect to an IBM JVM (or vice-versa) then I have no idea what will happen, although JRockit seems to be fairly friendly in this regard.
4. I don't know ***all*** the caveats.

Comment: ohhh thank you so much this code is exactly what i need.but why it give me the descriptors list size equals 0?

Comment: There's a few possibilities. One is that you may not have any other java processes running on the same host. Another is that you may be running your scanner using a 32bit JVM, but your other JVMs are 64bit (or vice-versa). Best thing to do is to test with [jps][1].    [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html